# Вызов функций для элементов массива

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, shortcode

Сценарий следующий: пользователь отмечает "чекбоксами" варианты в соответствующем мета-поле в админ.панели и на выходе (в зависимости от выбранного варианта) выполняется shortcode.

Сам php-код я написал, но он получается громоздким. Хотелось бы уточнить, как правильно его оптимизировать.
Вот абстрактный пример для одного варианта:

```
if ( in_array( 'Чай', get_field('meal_type') ) ) 
                        {   
                            the_content();                                                                
                            do_shortcode("[tea]");                               
                        }
```

Здесь все работает и выводится информация так, как нужно. Но если таких полей много, то код получается громоздким (если описывать раздельно).

Как сразу объединить при выборке нужные категории мета-полей и выполнять для них соответствующие шорткоды и выводить информацию после функции `the_content()`?

Например:

```
the_content();

array(){
'Чай'  -> do_shortcode['tea'],
'Кофе' -> do_shortcode['coffee'],
...
}
```

Comment: ну так получи имена полей из бд, зачем ты их в коде вручную пишешь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```
$meals = array( 'Чай', 'Кофе', 'Вино', 'Пиво' );

$meal = get_field( 'meal_type' );
if ( in_array( $meal, $meals, true ) ) {
    the_content();
    echo do_shortcode( "[$meal]" );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за мысль! Попробую оттолкнуться от этого решения.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.